# Shalom Aleichem in Kiddush Levanah

Tags: blessing, moon, kiddush-levanah

Why do we say Shalom Aliechem in Kiddush Levanah? And what should one do if there are no other people around (or not enough people around)?

Comment: What if you have one other person, do you say it three times or just once?

Comment: @SethJ When my rebbi had to say KL, he took me outside and said shalom aleichem to me thrice.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8196/kiddush-levanah-saying-aleichem-sholom-with-the-other-person?lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Original sorce for this *Minhag* is a **Maseches Sofrim**.

> ואומר לחברו שלש פעמים שלום, וילך לביתו
>   בלב טוב

The reasons given are:

- The **Mahril** based on the Gemara in Sanhedrin 42A says since it is such a great *Mitzvah* it is as if we are greeting the *Shechina*.Therfore when we say *Shalom Aleichem* we are in a sense greeting the *Shechina*.
- **Matteh Moshe**(540) adds to his Rebbi's reasoning that after wishing bad upon our enemies we are telling Hashem that these people are not included among those whose downfall we seek.
- A third reason given is just like after making a *Bracha* (blessing) on food, we partake of it so to here after we make a *Bracha* on the moon we partake of it by use its light to identify a friend.

In response to what to do if there is not enough people around the Mateh Moshe says you greet one person three times. The Rebbe of the Mahril say that if you have three people you
say to one friend twice ‘Shalom Aleichem’ and to the other once.

Summarized from:

1) http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%207%20Ron.pdf

2) http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/140/Q1/

Comment: Anything on the second part of the question: What to do if no one's around?

Comment: You can tell everyone made Kiddush levanah

Comment: I once observed an Odom Godol (at the Kosel) say "Sholom Aleichem Aleichem Sholom" x3 to himself, or to nobody in particular. That would only make sense according to the first, and possibly second reasons.

Comment: WHO is the adam godol ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not comfortable saying. But I can sat that he is a Ben Shivim, and has been a Rosh Yeshiva for decades, and has hundreds (thousands?) of talmidim, va'ani besocham.

Comment: AY, If you register your account, you'll be recognized by mi.yodeya as one person, and you'll be able to leave comments as such instead of improperly as answers.

Comment: see this answer for another reason for the minhag: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8208/603

Comment: What you mention from the Maharil is probably based on the idea that מקבל פני אורחין  is also like קבלת השכינה.

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't say it on your own, but you can say it after Kiddush Levana to the first three people you meet. (I was advised this in my youth.)

Comment: Would you mind including in your answer the identity of your adviser?

Comment: @msh210, I don't think that's strictly necessary.

Comment: @SethJ, I agree completely. It'd be more informative, though.

Comment: If I recall correctly. it was casual, passing advice from a *madrich*/counsellor whose name I have forgotten.

Comment: *Administrative note: This was posted as an answer to another question and moved hither.*

Answer (score 3):

Since the first question was answered already I will address the second one only.

The [Avnei Yashfei 3:50:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=874&st=&pgnum=97&hilite=) writes that if one says kiddush levana alone there is no inyan to search out for someone to say shalom aleichem since he said the passuk Tipal aleiheim and no one heard him(see @simchas Torah answer -Mattaeh Moshe reason).He adds by saying if one said it with a tzibbur even though he said that passuk quietly ,the fact that the tzibbur knows he says the passuk he still should say shalom aliechem.

Comment: In this situation I usually leave "שלום עליכם" in my gchat status until I get three responses. I admit it's more for fun than anything else