# If one says "Kiddush Levana" alone, does one say "Sholom Aleichem"?

Tags: halacha, tzibur-community, kiddush-levanah

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shalom Aleichem in Kiddush Levanah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/shalom-aleichem-in-kiddush-levanah)

If one says "Kiddush Levana" alone, does one say "Sholom Aleichem"? Since there is no-one to answer, it does not seem to make sense. Or maybe there's a deeper meaning?