# Shalom Aleichem of Kiddush Levanah to a Kattan

Tags: minhag, minor-katan-child, kiddush-levanah

In most aspects of Halachah a Kattan is out of the realm of the Mitzvos.

As for the Minhag of saying Shalom Aleichem during Kiddush Levanah I was wondering whether there is any preference to say it to an adult. Since a Kattan doesn't "do" or "accomplish" ritual factors it would be akin to greeting a lamppost or being a human whom we care for he is no different from any adult.
Or, perhaps it would depend on which reason given by [SimchasTorah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1862/9259) we'd go by.

Being that there is no great or serious ramifications one way or the other, I'd be happy with whatever can be brought to the table, be it anecdotes, Svaros, insults, sources etc.

Comment: doubtful that saying shalom alechem in kiddsuh levanna is a mitzvah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Rabbi Chayim Kanievski](http://www.shut-halacha.co.il/q/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F-497?param=2-25) (*She'elat Rav*), one can say "*shalom aleichem*" to a *kattan*.

[This discussion](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=874&st=&pgnum=97) is about the general *chiyuv* of a *kattan* in *Kiddush Levanah*.